# Yoast installation asks me for my SFTP/FTP details

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

I am a WordPress user and I made a website using WordPress and I got the paid hosting and paid domain from godaddy.

I wanted to do the SEO for my website. After seeing many tutorials most of them recommended yoast SEO plugin to me.

I clicked on the install button for the Yoast SEO plugin and suddenly a dialog box appeared asking me for my SFTP or FTP credentials but Godaddy hosting had provided me with ftps credentials and not SFTP or FTP so how should I continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this happening for all plugins you install or just Yoast. Usually it can be solved by adding this line in wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

FTP or sFTP are same. Just use Port 22 to make it sftp and for FTP port is 21

Comment: This is just happening for Yoast and I am neither using FTP or sFTP I am using FTPS

Comment: Thank you so much Devmaster, I added this line of code which you told to add and it worked!!. I have been struggling from this error from past 2 weeks. Thank you so much.